# Open TFS Git repo with Code

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code can open Git repos.

How can I open a Git repo that's in Team Foundation Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The info that I needed was that the url to clone looks like this: https://company.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/project/_git/team

So the command looks like:

```
git clone https://company.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/project/_git/team
```

If I try to open this url the clone does not work:
https://company.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/project/

Answer (score 4):

If you have the Git repo cloned locally then all you need to do is go into the repo directory and type

> code .

this assumes you followed the tips in setup [Code Setup](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/setup).

If you have not set up code to work from the command line you can also just open the folder with your source in and Code will pick it up and the Git support will work.

more about Git support can be found here [Version 
Control in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/versioncontrol).

Answer (score 0):

just open the folder. no project file needed.